# How can I stop EF 7 mapping an entity property to a column?

Tags: entity-framework-core

In EF 6, I can add a `NotMapped` attribute to the property, then it will not be mapped to a column. How can I do this in EF 7?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We haven't implemented data annotations yet. (See [#107](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/107)) You should be able to do it using the Fluent API.

```csharp
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Ignore(e => e.NotMappedProperty);
```

Comment: Got it. But I noticed that `Ignore` method is not available in EF 7 beta 1, that's ok. Thanks.

Comment: @Ricky How did you fix it if Ignore was not available?

Comment: @fiso in beta 8, it supports `NotMapped` attribute, so just mark your property of entity with `[NotMapped]`

Comment: In RC1, I found the `NotMapped` attribute caused a `StackOverflowException` on an unmapped readonly property. I had to resort to using the `Ignore()` method above to solve it.

Answer (score 13):

Just to add on to Ricky and bricelam's answer,

There are two ways to ignore a property:

1. Data annotations on model

   ```
   public class Blog
   {
       public int BlogId { get; set; }
       public string Url { get; set; }

       [NotMapped]
       public DateTime LoadedFromDatabase { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Fluent API overriding OnModelCreating

   ```
   class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Ignore(b => b.LoadedFromDatabase);
        }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public DateTime LoadedFromDatabase { get; set; }
    }
   ```

Documentation available [here](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/included-properties.html).